# Powershell Join Path returns array

Tags: arrays, powershell, join, path

I am trying to create folders at the start of my script and afterwords create files in those. To create paths i use `md -Force $path`, i also used just to test similar methods

```
if(![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path)){
    [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($path)
}
```

After creating the path i like to build the filename + path of the file i want to write to, i went 2 ways:

```
Join-Path $path "myfile.txt"
```

which leads to the result that i get an string array as result, with two records, both building the same path `$path\myfile.txt`
Also using

```
[System.IO.Path]::Combine($path, "myfile.txt")
```

Returns the same string array, with two records (even though the combine method has only a definition for returning a string)

This behavior only occurs if i create the folders before, so i would like to know what causes these results and how can i avoid them.

My Setup is Powershell 3 (customer "wish") with Win7.

Comment: please add a bit more of your code, is the join-path used in a foreach block ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `$path` contains an array.

```
PS C:\> $path = 'C:\Temp'
PS C:\> $res = Join-Path $path 'file.txt'
PS C:\> $res.GetType().FullName
System.String
PS C:\> $res
C:\Temp\file.txt
PS C:\> $path = 'C:\Temp', 'C:\Windows'
PS C:\> $res = Join-Path $path 'file.txt'
PS C:\> $res.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
PS C:\> $res
C:\Temp\file.txt
C:\Windows\file.txt
```

Comment: hey, thanks. called my function with parenthesis. which made an array out of my path.